# Search in multi-level menu navigation drawer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The problem I have is my search function returns all the items from category where search phrase is occurring.

Code pen: https://codepen.io/simonsnetwork/pen/GRGeNXB?editors=0010
`

```
computedItemsList() {
      let searchString = this.search.toLowerCase()
      return this.menu_items_list.filter(function search(row) {
        return Object.keys(row).some((key) => {
          if (typeof row[key] === 'string' && key === 'title') {
            return row[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1
          } else if (row[key] && typeof row[key] === 'object') {
            return search(row[key])
          }
          return false
        })
      })
    }
```

`

I'm using recurrence search function which looks for the title in child elements, maybe it could be easier solution then I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
  methods:{
      filterSubItems(subItems){
         let searchString = this.search.toLowerCase();
         if(!searchString){
          return subItems;
        }
        return subItems.filter((row)=> {
          return row.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
        });
      }
  },
  computed:{
    
    computedItems() {
      let searchString = this.search.toLowerCase();
      if(!searchString){
        return this.menu_items_list;
      }
      return this.menu_items_list.filter((row)=> {
    
        return row.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||(this.filterSubItems(row.items).length>0)
      })
    
    }
  }
```

and template

```
<v-list-item v-for="child in filterSubItems(item.items)" :key="child.title" :to="child.link" dense link>
  <v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-title>{{ child.title }}</v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```

Comment: great answer Sir!, I can buy you a coffee if you want

Comment: Salim, I have a question off topic, is it possible using your way to render menu items based on the permissionGroup object in menu? I have tried to use this two functions together but with same result as before  codepen: https://codepen.io/simonsnetwork/pen/YzvgVBa

Comment: I created new issue (question) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74731002/return-multi-level-menu-drawer-navigation-items-based-on-permissions