# Return multi-level menu drawer navigation items based on permissions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Function doesn't return particular item, instead of it returns whole group where the given item exists.

In given codepen example: https://codepen.io/simonsnetwork/pen/YzvgVBa?editors=1011

user has permissions:

```
userPermissionGroup: [
        "dictionary_company_high_department",
        "dictionary_company_department",
        "user_user"
      ]
```

And menu returns entire groups in the menu where items with those permissions exists instead of just three items in two groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution in the codepen: https://codepen.io/simonsnetwork/pen/YzvgVBa?editors=0111

Basically I can use computed properties in Vue stacked together, so I created two computed properties: `filterSubItems(subItems)` for menu search and `filterSubItemsByPermissions(subItems)` for menu permissions.

```
<v-list-item
    v-for="child in filterSubItems(filterSubItemsByPermissions(item.items))"
    :key="child.title"
    :to="child.link"
    dense
    link
    >
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title>{{ child.title }}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
</v-list-item>
```